# Proper way of implementing & using ui-router - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im building an app using the MEAN Stack where each feature is a component. By that I mean I have structured each main feature a specific module in the back end so that its easy to scale and debug in future.

My front end structure is something like this:

[image]

**Points to note:**

1. The side bar will contain a menu which can used to navigate through the app.
2. The header is search bar.
3. The main content section is where my actual app will be. The main content section is basically the `ui-view` section.

When the user taps on a link from the menu on the sidebar it will update the view on the main content. The sidebar and header will always be there. The main content will change based on the state the user is in i.e **(Dashboard, Profile,Settings etc)**

**My Code:**

```
var knowledgeBaseCtrl = angular.module('knowledgeBaseCtrl', ['ngAnimate','ui.router'])

knowledgeBaseCtrl.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

 $stateProvider

 // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================

 // nested list with custom controller
.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile'
})

// nested list with custom controller
.state('knowledgebase', {
    templateUrl: './knowledgeBase.ejs'
})

// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**The profile state is default state, this is where the user goes when they login. That is the state where I have placed the `UI-VIEW`. All the scripts, dependencies, css files are being called in the profile state.**

**My Question:**

How to properly implement a ui-router, so that only the main content div changes and sidebar and header are always visible. Each view that needs to be pushed into the `ui-view` (main content) will needs its own scripts and css files to be loaded. I am not sure where to place them. Whats the proper way of implementing this structure.

I might not have explained this very well. So if you have any question please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check it out https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin